# Why Scala can't inferred type of method without parentheses and dots

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I wrote simple code, that returns immutable map of characters and their indexes as vector:

```
def indexes(string: String): Map[Char, Vector[Int]] = (0 until string.length).
  foldLeft(Map[Char, Vector[Int]]()){
    (m, i) => m + (string(i) -> m.getOrElse(string(i), Vector()).:+(i))
  }
```

For example:

```
println(indexes("Mississippi"))
// Map(M -> Vector(0), i -> Vector(1, 4, 7, 10), s -> Vector(2, 3, 5, 6), p -> Vector(8, 9))
```

Why Scala can't inferred that `m.getOrElse(string(i), Vector()) :+ i` is `Vector[Int]` and compile it? I should wrote `m.getOrElse(string(i), Vector()).:+(i)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll work fine with the Map value parenthesized:

```
def indexes(string: String): Map[Char, Vector[Int]] = (0 until string.length).
  foldLeft(Map[Char, Vector[Int]]()){
    (m, i) => m + (string(i) -> (m.getOrElse(string(i), Vector()) :+ i))
  }

indexes("Mississippi")
// res1: Map[Char,Vector[Int]] = Map(M -> Vector(0), i -> Vector(1, 4, 7, 10), s -> Vector(2, 3, 5, 6), p -> Vector(8, 9))
```

Without parenthesizing the Map value, the `(k -> a :+ b)` key-value portion of the code below will be treated as `(k -> a) :+ b`, hence causes compilation error:

```
    (m, i) => m + (string(i) -> m.getOrElse(string(i), Vector()) :+ i)

// <console>:28: error: value :+ is not a member of (Char, Vector[Int])
```